# How to export Properties -> Details for devices under Windows Device Manager?

Tags: windows, device, administrator

Under Windows 7 or equivalent:

I want to export all of this information at once to a txt:

Go to Control Panel -> Device Manager -> Disk Drives -> Volume0 -> Properties -> Details:

All properties in the dropdown menu, export all instead of doing it myself one by one, for example 'Device description', 'Hardware Ids', and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy to do.If it is windows XP or 7
Go

```
Start-Programs-Accessories-System tools-System Information
```

or

```
Start-Run-msinfo32.exe-ok-System Information
```

Now Go to `File-Export-Select Directory-Save`
A text file containing the system information will be saved to the directory!!

Reference

[How to save](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msinfo_save_text.mspx?mfr=true)
[How to open System Information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308549)

Comment: @Garner please accept this answer if it helped you. You'll gain some rep, me too, and others will benefit from your question.

Comment: The 'Device Class guid' for example is missing in Storage section.

Comment: @Garner.Ok.Thanks mate for the advice.It will help me in giving quality answer in future.